# Use Espresso to check contents of a web page loaded in the browser

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

I currently have a test which simulates clicking on a button in a dialog box which then loads a Google Forms document from my Google Drive:

```
@Test
public void testTakeSurveyNow() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
    onView(withText(R.string.survey2))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withText(R.string.now))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
            .perform(click());
    Uri surveyUri = Uri.parse(context.getString(R.string.survey2_uri));
    intended(allOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW), hasData(surveyUri)));
    startApp();
    Assert.assertTrue(prefs.contains(SharedPreferenceKeys.SURVEY2_DATE));
    onView(withText(startsWith("BBCT")))
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withText(R.string.survey1))
            .check(doesNotExist());
}
```

The problem I encountered is that `survey2_uri` was set to an incorrect address. I noticed this while running the test and fixed it. However, I would like to fix my test to help me avoid this kind of error in the future. How do I assert that the correct document is shown, possibly looking for some expected text which is most likely unique to the document? Originally, I assumed that the document will be loaded in the device's browser. This leads me to believe I can use Espresso Web. The document suggests something like

```
onWebView()
      .withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "teacher"))
      .check(webMatches(getText(), containsString("Socrates")));
```

I'm just not sure what to use for the parameters of `findElement()` nor how to determine what values to use here.

To make matters worse, I have recently started to believe that my assumption is false that the document will open in the browser. It is possible that the document will open in another app, such as Google Drive. This possibility seriously complicates this test. Any suggestions?

Comment: "This leads me to believe I can use Espresso Web" -- I think that is only for a `WebView` in your own app. You would have to use UI Automator for this sort of cross-app integration test.

Comment: @CommonsWare That makes sense! I guess I'll have to dig into `UiSelector` to see if I can figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/a/img")).check(....);
```

That is a late response but probably you can use `Locator.XPATH` inspecting XPATH from developer menu on the browser.

Comment: Will this work for a link that opens a web page in a 3rd party app such as the default browser?

Comment: After reading my old question here, I'm not even sure what I was asking. I'm missing some important details, such as the application code that is being tested.